# Допустимые имена полей в БД Mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Здравствуйте!

какие допустимые имена могут быть поля в таблице Mysql?

к примеру: section_title, sectionTitle, section-title

сейчас я использую такой вид: section_title, но слышал что можно использовать sectionTitle, но почему то у меня второй способ не работает.

подскажите пожалуйста как правильно.

Comment: что значит не работает? они регистронезависимые, насколько я помню.  А так - неужели этого нет в документации,

Comment: не работает, значит не работает или не отображается!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Допустимые символы](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/identifiers.html)

> Certain objects within MySQL, including database, table, index,
>   column, alias, view, stored procedure, partition, tablespace, resource
>   group and other object names are **known as identifiers**.

Идентификаторы могут состоять из базовых латинских символов, цифр 0-9, $ и подчеркивания. Могут начинаться с цифры, но не могут состоять только из них.

*[Регистр](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/identifier-case-sensitivity.html)*

Во избежании проблем в именах с разным регистром, лучше всего принять согласованное соглашение, например, всегда создавать и ссылаться на базы данных и таблицы с использованием строчных имен. Это соглашение рекомендуется для максимальной переносимости и простоты использования.

*Также*

Как имена таблиц и баз данных хранятся на диске и используются в MySQL, зависит от системной переменной `lower_case_table_names`, которую вы можете установить при запуске `mysqld`.